Which Hard Drive?
I have an Dell Alienware and during pre-boot up it gave an error saying a hard drive has an error.  I am totally fine replacing the hard drive, but this machine has 5 physical hard drives in it.  It says Hard Drive 11 - S/N xxxxxxxxxx.
How do I determine which physical drive has an error.  When I go into Computer Management - it shows them all as healthy.

At least under linux, when I do smartctl -i /dev/sdX  one of the attributes it has is the device serial number.  Maybe you can do something similar with Crystal Disk or a Linux boot disk?

there's windows smart tools

look at the serial number label

Disconnecting the drives physically, connecting one by one and observing the pre-boot errors will probably allow you to determine the faulty drive. If you know which physical drive holds your OS, connect it last to avoid booting the OS in vain.
Taking a suspect drive out and examining it may also help, as each drive may (should) have a sticker with its serial number. To further confirm, you can take all the drives out; if each has a sticker with its own serial number and only one number matches the error then you will know for sure.
Physical actions seem less elegant than solving this problem with software, there's always a risk of breaking something or not connecting back in the right way. Still it is a way, in some cases maybe the ultimate way.

tbh, if I was doing this, I'd grab my label printer and print enough of the serials that I can ID a drive once I pop the case. Its a bit of work 'once' per drive but without server grade blinkenlighten, this feels like something that'd make things simpler

If there's an error - its likely detected by smart, and you can check it at a lower level. This only works with Sata, not NVMe drives, but I'm assuming we're talking traditional mechanical hard drives or sata SSDs.
For determining what's wrong on a hard drive - I tend to favour gsmartcontrol as a front end (I've been playing with Diskovery as well. Its got a few nice features, such as being able to work with raid, and a more polished UI, but I've used gsmartcontrol for years, and its front end for a proven system. For the sake of brevity and simplicity, I'll stick to talking about gsmart control)
It'll give you the serial number on each drive

As well as the attributes

This generally shows/highlights any attributes that have failed, but I don't have any failed drives now
I'd run the short self tests on each drive to confirm
Unfortunately on a consumer system, there's no 'easy' way to ID which drive is which. On servers you often had the option of blinking a hotswap drive but that's not a consumer level feature. That said, it should be trivial to check against the drive label on an offline system. Hard drive 11 might map to a physical port, but you'd need to consult your manual to be sure.

I will definitely look at this. Challenge is I have 3 NVME and 2 SATA drives, and an external drive. Hence why I wanted to try a software based identification.

Nvme might not have smart readouts. Either software I have suggested would give you that brand of the drive
